# Error 405: Method Not Allowed Maven default repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

I was trying to publish my project on maven by using `mvn deploy` but it seems that I'm getting a problem doing it... I don't have a personal repository and I wanted to publish my repo to maven central repository without much success...

The error is:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project telegram: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact ...jar... from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Failed to transfer file: ...jar.... Return code is: 405, ReasonPhrase: Method Not Allowed.
```

I'm sorry if the format of the error is not particulary good, but I hope it's good enough.

My pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>id</groupId>
<artifactId>id</artifactId>
<version>version</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Why are you redefining already the defaults of Maven in your pom file? If you want to distribute to Maven Central please read here: http://central.sonatype.org/

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't know maven very well... How do I use that repo?

Comment: You can use the repos which is by default already defined. The distributionManagement only makes sense if you have defined a repository manager where you can deploy your own result https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not the issue you've encountered, but I've noticed that an unhelpful 405 Not Allowed error message may also appear during maintenance windows. When accessing the staging deploy URL in a browser: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2,

Then a more helpful error message appears:

> Method not allowed during maintenance.